# Swift 4 filter json array into sub arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I got this code:

```
let arrData = [["id": "1",
                        "name": "Apple",
                        "category": "Fruit"],
                       ["id": "2",
                        "name": "Pie",
                        "category": "Fruit"],
                       ["id": "3",
                        "name": "Tomato",
                        "category": "Vegetable"]]

        let categorieNames = Array(Set(arrData.map({$0["category"]!})))
        var arrResult:[[String]] = []
        for i in 0..<categorieNames.count {

            let categories = arrData.filter({$0["category"] == categorieNames[i]}).map({$0["name"]!})
            arrResult.append(categories)
        }
        print("result : \(arrResult)")
```

it works perfectly with an Array.
But now I get my data from a json:

```
[{"id":"1",
  "name":"Apple",
  "category":"Fruits"},
{"id":"2",
 "name":"Pie",
 "category":"Fruits"},
{"id":"3",
 "name":"Tomato",
 "category":"Vegetable"}]
```

**here is my struct and my decode function:**

```
struct MarketStruct : Decodable {
    let id                    : Int?
    let name                  : String?
    let category              : String?
}



  class MarketsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, NetworkDelegate {

    var myMarkets : [MarketStruct]?
    var categorieNames : [Any] = []
    var categorieArray:[[String]] = []


    func didFinish(result: Data) {
        do {
            self.myMarkets  =  try JSONDecoder().decode([MarketStruct].self, from: result)
                categorieNames = Array(Set(myMarkets!.map({ ["category": $0] })))
            for i in 0..<categorieNames.count {
                let categories = myMarkets!.filter({$0["category"] == categorieNames[i]}).map({["name": $0]!})
                categorieArray.append(categories)
            }
        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error:", jsonErr)
        }
                self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

I got an error at the filter part: 
*Type 'MarketStruct' has no subscript members*

what must I change that the above Array code works with my JSON array?

thanks for your help.

**edit my current code:**

```
 self.myMarkets = try JSONDecoder().decode([MarketStruct].self, from: result)
        categorieNames = Array(Set(myMarkets.map({$0.category })))

            for i in 0..<categorieNames.count {
                    let categories = myMarkets!.filter({$0.category == categorieNames[i]}).map({$0.name})
                    categorieArray.append(categories as! [String])
        }

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error:", jsonErr)
        }
        self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
```

it compiles with error: **Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11**

if I comment *categorieNames = Array(Set(myMarkets.map({$0.category })))* out it compiles without errors

Comment: `myMarkets!.filter({$0.category...` instead? Because `$0` is now a `MarketStruct`, so to access `category`, you just have to do `myMarketStruct.category`. But when you did previously `let categories = arrData.filter({$0["category"]`, `$0` was a Dict, so to access the `category`, you need to do `["category"]` (that's a subscript).

Comment: Do you have an error in console, because according to your `struct`, `id` is a `Int`, but in the JSON you gave, it's a `String`. You should get an error. Else, `categorieNames2 = Array(Set(myMarkets.flatMap({$0.category})))` could fix your issue (because you have optionals stuff I think). and the first time you did `map({$0["category"]!}` not `map({["category":$0]!}` that's not the same type of data and doesn't match with you declaration, and after you do `categorieNames[i]`, which you expect to be a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the compiler error because the `category` property is optional and therefore does not conform to `Hashable`.

`Set` requires that all elements conform to that.

One way to get around that is to use `flatMap` instead of `map`, which has the added capability of filtering out the `nil` values.

`categorieNames = Array(Set(myMarkets.flatMap({$0.category })))`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues in the code

- In the JSON the type of `id` is `String` not `Int`
- The members in the struct are supposed to be non-optional.
- The `categorieNames` array is supposed to be specific `[String]`, not unspecified `[Any]`
- In the filter line access the category by dot notation, not key subscription (Error 1)
- Rather than declaring `myMarkets` as optional, initialize it as an empty array (Error 2)
- Don't use ugly index-based for loop, use fast enumeration (not really an issue)

And why do you map `myMarkets` to an array of dictionaries?

---

```
struct MarketStruct : Decodable {
    let id                    : String
    let name                  : String
    let category              : String
}

var myMarkets = [MarketStruct]()
var categorieNames = [String]()
var categorieArray = [[String]]()

let jsonString = """
[{"id":"1", "name":"Apple", "category":"Fruits"},
 {"id":"2", "name":"Pie", "category":"Fruits"},
 {"id":"3", "name":"Tomato", "category":"Vegetable"}]
""" 

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    myMarkets = try JSONDecoder().decode([MarketStruct].self, from: data)
    let categorieNames = Array(Set(myMarkets.map { $0.category }))

    for categoryName in categorieNames {
        let categories = myMarkets.filter({$0.category == categoryName}).map({$0.name})
        categorieArray.append(categories)
    }
    print(categorieArray)

} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer :) no i know the issues. But what so mean that i map myMarkets a dictionary?

Comment: `myMarkets!.map({ ["category": $0] }` maps the array of `MarketStruct` to an array of dictionaries.

Comment: Hmm i found this on the internet. I will Check tomorrow if i need this. Thanks for your help

Comment: I need the categorieNames as sectionNames in UiCollectionView

Comment: That's a new question